# HierarchicalDataTempalte c ItemTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
class DisplayTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        var baseClass = item as BaseClass;

        switch (baseClass.Type)
        {
            case A:
                return TemplateA;                   
            case B:
                return TemplateB;                 
            default:
                return null;

        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="key" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Streams, Mode=OneWay}" 
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource displayTemplateSelector}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>


<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type A}" x:Key="a">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type B}" x:Key="b">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

На данном этапе все работает. Но как только я захочу установить `ItemSource` и `ItemTemplate` для одного из A или B шаблона, получаю исключение:

> Для двусторонней сборки требуется Path или XPath.

и предупреждение в выводе:

`Both 'ItemTemplate' and 'ItemTemplateSelector' are set;  'ItemTemplateSelector' will be ignored. TreeViewItem:'TreeViewItem' (Name='')`

В чем проблема?

---

UDP:

проблема была из-за привязки в шаблонaх A,B.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
```

нужно было привязываться к конкретному полю.

Comment: Если вы хотите Mode=TwoWay, то нужно задать Path в Binding. Если нет, то нужно задать Mode=OneWay. По поводу предупреждения, нужно   либо убрать TextBlock, либо DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: @Vlad, да так и стоит OneWay, но я пробовал разными способами. Selector убрать? мне без него не обойтись)

Comment: Тогда шаблон уберите. Должно быть что-то одно. Вы либо сами выбираете, либо пользуетесь тем, что задали в разметке. Где стоит? Я не про ItemSource, я про TextBlock.

Comment: @Vlad, HierarchicalDataTemplate позволяет задать шаблон для себя и для дочерхних элементов через ItemTemplate. так что боюсь дело не в этом

Comment: у вас есть возможность написать MCVE?

Comment: собрался написать, и проблема нашлась)